# Laravel auth middleware returns route not defined

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to secure some routes wherein only authenticated users can access it.

I've followed instructions on grouping my web routes on an `auth middle ware`, so I did my `routes/web.php` it like this...

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/feed', [FeedController::class, 'feed']);
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'profile']);

});

Route::get('/', [LandingController::class, 'landing']);
```

and my `App/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` like this....

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('/');
    }
}
```

but when I access these guarded routes unauthenticated, it gives me error saying

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [/] not defined.
```

Can someone point me on the right way here?

Comment: the `route` helper is for using route names not URIs

Comment: @lagbox I tried adding `->name('login')` on the `/` web route and I also changed the parameter with `login` of the `route` helper in the middleware class. and it works, but I don't understand why it worked. could you explain it?

Comment: Change to `return redirect('/');`